# how to add cash on delivery charges by my custom module magento

Tags: magento

HI I want to add some charges on cash on delivery, I dont know where to do that
what I need to extend or what observer I need to call and how I can get and update quote price can any body explain briefly to me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Before you start thinking about code you need to describe (if only to yourself) how your new  "cash on delivery" feature will work with Magento.  When will users be prompted for this choice?  What needs to be added to the backend order information panes? etc.

Once you know that, you can start to identify the blocks/phtml and model logic you'll need to change/add-to in order to implement your feature.

Comment: thanks alan storm, I want to to add custom cash on delivery charges  , whenever user check on cashondelivery charges I want to add cod fee to the total amount, and Alan I am clear about blocks and phtml and models logic I have have read your blogs on your website they so help full But I didn't find any for my this question

Comment: Alan Storm you didn't answer my question..?